# Adding Tests with a JUnit Theory

Tags: junit, junit4, junit-rule, junit-runner

Is there any way to use a rule to add additional tests? For example, I would like to convert the Theories runner to a rule, but I haven't been able to find a way to make Rules add additional tests.

Comment: This is not possible. Rules cannot add tests. You need a `Runner` for that. Can you explain why you want that?

Comment: We need to combine the functionality of Spring's runner and the Theories runner. I was hoping to use rules, since Runners are very low-level (comparatively). Guess I'll have to write a custom runner.

Comment: We once had the same problem with combining the Parameterized and the Parallelized runners - we wrote a custom runner for that as well.